# What is the "Access Type: Bearer-Only" setting in Keycloak server (not client adapter) good for?

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

According to the Keycloak documentation at https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_service_accounts, a client that uses the "Client Credentials Grant" flow should be configured in the server as "Access-Type: Confidential" and with only "Service Accounts Enabled: true". That works well and I can fetch JWTs and use them with "Authentication Bearer" in HTTP requests between backend services.

In the Keycloak admin GUI I can select **"Access-Type: bearer-only"** as well though and that's described as for "web services that never requires a browser login". Sounds perfect for the "Client Credentials Grant" flow to me. Doesn't work though. When trying to get a JWT with `http --auth $clientId:$clientSecret --form POST https://keycloak/auth/realms/testrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token grant_type=client_credentials`, it always returns with a Bad Request:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "Bearer-only not allowed"
}
```

So what is the Keycloak Admin GUI's setting "Access-Type: bearer-only" good for?

P.S.: Confusingly there is a Java Client Adapter setting with the same name described at https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_java_adapter_config - I'm not talking about that.

Comment: I believe you can find your answer here: http://www.janua.fr/understanding-oauth2openid-client-authentication-methods-with-redhat-sso/

Comment: Thanks @andrija. From the article I would understand that "bearer-only" is a configuration for a service that only *receives* requests using "Authentication Bearer" and never makes outgoing requests. The reason it has to be known to Keycloak at all is problably so that one can configure resource specific roles. Can anybody confirm?